# 16 tiles and not 17 ( GPU + CPU rendering )

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

in my system I have

- 8c 16t CPU ( AMD Ryzen 9 4900HS )
  -and a GPU ( Nvidia RTX 2060 max-q )
  when I try to render with both it only shows 16 tiles
  shouldn't it be 17 tiles 16 threads from the CPU and 1 from the GPU

however there is a fast tile this seems to be the GPU and other 15 slow CPU tiles

Comment: Did you try set the thread count manually?

Comment: I tried it but it does not confirm the solution since you can launch more tiles than the threads and GPUs your system has